# Sefer Ginas Egoz Rav Schacter

Tags: jewish-books, tzitzis

Where can I get the sefer Ginas Egoz by Rav Herschel Schacter which discusses the topic of Techeiles amongst other things.

Also if anyone knows where to get his other seforim as well.

Comment: ginas egoz is not "on techeiles" - it has a number of sugyas arranged according to sections of shulchan aruch, and one of them is on techeiles (the second one in orech chayim).

Comment: Thanks for correction I have seen it quoted in regards to techeiles,that's why looking for it.

Comment: I don't remember where I got it, but publisher is Flatbush Beth Hamedrosh (or was when I got it) if that helps your search.

Comment: I don't know the reason of the down vote,just looking for info on a sefer which I have seen qouted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R. Schachter's sefarim are available at the annual YU Seforim Sale that takes place every February or so. Most of them can be read electronically through the Otzar Hachachmah database.

However, if you're just interested in the article on techeiles, which is only six pages long, those pages are available online via the techelet website:

[page 13](http://www.tekhelet.info/111037/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%90)

[page 14](http://www.tekhelet.info/111037/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%91)

[page 15](http://www.tekhelet.info/111037/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%92)

[page 16](http://www.tekhelet.info/111037/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%93)

[page 17](http://www.tekhelet.info/111037/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%94)

[page 18](http://www.tekhelet.info/111037/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%95)